# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable even when the variable is set Cordova

Tags: android, angular, bash, cordova

I am trying to create a mobile application from my angular app and am using cordova for converting the web app to mobile. I had followed all requirements given on the [apache cordova official guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/) and installed Android studio as well using [this online guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux).

I had also followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiIGcmHtDDE) youtube tutorial which explained to easily convert the angular app into a cordova application using these steps:

```
- Create a cordova project within the angular project using cordova create <proj_name>
- Create a soft link, adding a link between www folder in cordova project and dist folder of angular project
- Create build
- Add android to cordova project
- Cordova run android
```

Everything goes fine until `cordova run android` where it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I checked to see on stackoverflow of any errors and there were in fact a few similar issues, which should have been resolved by editing the ~/.bashrc file and adding:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

However, even after logging out and logging in again, several times, using `source ~/.bashrc` as well hasn't helped, the same error keeps popping up. I have also installed android studio and checked all paths the Sdk is installed and shows on the Sdk Manager in studio.

If I try to enter `android` in terminal it gives me an unknown command error, same goes with sdkmanager.

when I run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it gives me the correct path:

```
/home/username/Android/Sdk
```

when I run `cordova requirements` it gives me the following:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Gradle: installed /opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/gradle
Some of requirements check failed
```

running `cordova platform version android` in the project gives the following:

```
form version android
Installed platforms:
  android 8.1.0
Available platforms: 
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^1.0.0
  ios ^5.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0
```

I do not understand what seems to be missing? I have looked several times but can't seem to find the problem with my installation. Am i doing something naive here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue: For some reason data was being fetched from `npm cache`. To clear it, simply:

`sudo npm cache clean -f`

Maybe not the best approach, but for now it was the only way out